# getting acces to facebook API from extern swf with amfphp

Tags: php, actionscript-3, amfphp

I'm using AMFPHP 1.9 (i know its the older version but thats not important for now). and i want to communicate with flash. When O test my `facebookApi` service from the browser everything works fine and i get data back from the Facebook API.

But when I'm debugging with flash (AS 3.0) I'm getting the following error:

```
[SWF] C:\prototypeAfstuderen\test3.swf - 2925 bytes after decompression
User Error
/customers/d/5/a/navidmirzaie.com/httpd.www/facebook-facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
1238
AMFPHP_RUNTIME_ERROR
```

my service looks like bellow.

```
<?php               

include "../../facebook-facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php";     

class facebookApi{              

    private $fbApi;                 

    public function __construct(){          
        $this->fbApi = new Facebook(array(              
        'appId'=>'357570560984266',         
        'secret'=>'484752fa5b8748fd4ac578fc99cbdbaf',               
        'cookie' => true            
        ));     
    }               

    public function getLoggedinUser(){                  
        $data = $this->fbApi->api("/me/","GET",array('acces_token'=>$this->fbApi->getAccessToken()));                                   

        return $data;       

    }               

    public function getPictures(){      
        $data = $this->fbApi->api("/me/photos/","GET",array('acces_token'=>$this->fbApi->getAccessToken()));                    

        return $data;       
    }                                   

}

?>
```

I'm running my swf from my desktop computer and i want the data be accessible.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: No one out here who can help me out with this one?

Comment: Have you tried running it from the service browser?

Comment: @Ronnie what do u mean with service browser? U mean running it from the browser?

Comment: in your browser, go to http://yoursite.com/amfphp/browser (or wherever amfphp is installed). The `/browser` folder is your service browser

Comment: Ooh you mean that, yes that works well. I get data back from the api. But i think that has to do that the php running on my server and the session is still available. When i write a method to get my acces token and i go to the service browser the method returns the acces token. But i cant understand why it doesn't work with extern swf on my desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you try to access the API from your **local machine** (You're running it from Windows, in C:\prototypeAfstuderen\test3.swf), while it appears your api is running on a **remote server** (Seems like a Linux type path)?

Comment: I thought about that also, but that wasn't the solution.

Comment: I thought about that also, but that wasn't the solution. the issue is in the session. Php register the session on severside level and flash offcourse is clientside and they both react different ways. The reason why the api responds with the service browser is because it is serverside! i'll find a different way.